# Need help iterating over python dictionary values

Tags: python, dictionary, search

I'm working on a program to search through a dictionaries value set and perform a method on values that match a user input. I have to compare and sort these values.

This is the code I'm working with right now

**Code for value search and compare (very rough)**

```
import nation
import pickle

KK = 1000000

pickle_in = open("nationsDict.dat","rb")
d = pickle.load(pickle_in)

k = raw_input("Enter a continent: ")

for value in d.values():
    if k in d.values()[0]:
        print d.values()[0]
```

**Code for Nation class**

```
class Nations:

    KK = 1000000

    def __init__(self, ctry, cont, pop, area):
        self.country = ctry
        self.continent = cont
        self.population = float(pop)
        self.area = float(area)

    def popDensity(self):
        popDensity = (self.population*self.KK) / self.area
        popDensity = str(round(popDensity, 2))
        return popDensity
```

**Code for creating pickle dictionary**

```
import nation
import pickle


i=0
dictUN = {}

with open('UN.txt') as f:
    for line in f:

        """Data get from file"""
        elements = line.strip().split(",")

        n = nation.Nations(elements[0],elements[1],elements[2],elements[3])

        """Density"""
        n.popDensity()
        print "The density of", n.country, "is",n.popDensity(),"people per square mile."

        """Dictionary creation"""
        dictVal = (n.continent, n.population, n.area)
        dictUN.update({n.country: dictVal})


pickle_out = open("nationsDict.dat", "wb")
pickle.dump(dictUN, pickle_out)
pickle_out.close()
```

Here's a snippet from UN.txt

```
Mauritania,Africa,3.5,397954
Mauritius,Africa,1.3,787
Mexico,North America,120.3,761606
Micronesia,Australia/Oceania,.11,271
Monaco,Europe,.031,0.76
Mongolia,Asia,3.0,603909
Montenegro,Europe,.65,5019
Morocco,Africa,33.0,172414
```

My problems at this point are pretty contained to the value search and compare. Specifically, my program has to

1. Allow the user to search a continent (first element in value list)
2. Perform the method, Nations.popDensity (contained in nation class) on all matching countries
3. Compare the nations and return the top 5 density values per continent

I would say my one big question is how to handle the search of a dictionary by an element in a value. I've also considered about making a temp dictionary with the continent element as the key, but I'm not sure that would make my life any easier as I have to perform the popDensity method on it.

Any help is appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Just as there is list comprehension, there is dictionary comprehension... It's pretty cool stuff!  `d2 = {k:d[k] for k in d.keys() if <some_elem> in d[k]}` would give you a dict with a subset of the original dict that satisfies your requirements. You would have to fill in the `<some_elem> in d[k]` portion, because I haven't gone through all your code. You said that this is the main Q you have. Hopefull this gives you enough to solve it.

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly. Gonna be reading up on dictionary/list comprehension now :D

Comment: Glad the info was helpful! I've added it as an answer, so you can accept it if you're pleased with the results.

Answer (score 0):

1. Initialize pandas series object
2. Iterate through the dictionary.
3. If the continent matches:

   a. calculate the population density.

   b. if the value is larger than the smallest value in the pandas series:

   i. remove the last entry

   ii.append the value into the pandas series values and the country to the index

   iii. sort the pandas series object ascending = False

If you're going to do this repeatedly, then creating a continent->country dictionary definitely will save time.

Answer (score 0):

Glad it was helpful.  I'll add it as an answer, so you can accept it, if you like.

Just as there is list comprehension, there is dictionary comprehension... It's pretty cool stuff! `d2 = {k:d[k] for k in d.keys() if <some_elem> in d[k]}` would give you a dict with a subset of the original dict that satisfies your requirements. You would have to fill in the `<some_elem> in d[k]` portion, because I haven't gone through all your code. You said that this is the main Q you have. Hopefully this gives you enough to solve it.